# how is it possible that which -a shows two paths?

Tags: path, binary, which

When I execute `which -a python` I get two paths:

> /home/autumn/anaconda3/bin/python
>   /usr/bin/python

If I delete the directory ~/anaconda3 the first link to the python binary automatically vanishes.
How is it possible to create links like these? And how is the anaconda3 directory related to this without any special command?

Comment: yes my path variable includes /home/autumn/anaconda3/bin and also after only removing the anaconda3 directory the path variable automatically doesn't include the anaconda3 binary... how is that possible?!

Answer (score 4):

`which -a utility` will return *all* paths from `$PATH` where `utility` is found.

If the utility is found in more than one path, several results will be reported.

In your case, you have a `python` executable in both `/home/autumn/anaconda3/bin` and in `/usr/bin`, and both of these directories are listed in your `PATH` variable.  This is why `which -a python` returns two results.  Removing `python` from either location would remove the corresponding line from the output of the command.

To only see the first found instance of `python` in your path, use either

```
which python
```

or

```
command -v python
```

Related: [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)